# Show $R^*$ is not a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> $R = \mathbb{F}_3[x]/\langle X^3+X^2+1\rangle$ and $\alpha=[X]$ in $R$. How do you prove that the group $R^*$ is not cyclic?

We have shown that $\alpha$ is a unit in $R$ with order $8$ and that $\alpha^4$ and $-\alpha^4$ are two different elements in $R^*$ both with order 2.

Comment: Have you worked out what $R$ looks like yet?

Comment: Well, if you've got two distinct elements of order $2$, I'd say you're in pretty good shape!

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$x^3+x^2+1$ factors into the irreducibles $(x-1)$ and $(x^2+2x+2)$ over $\Bbb F_3$.

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, $R\cong \frac{\Bbb F_3[x]}{(x-1)}\times \frac{\Bbb F_3[x]}{(x^2+2x+2)}$.

Can you see what the two pieces look like, and how you can use this to see the units of $R$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: How many elements of order two have a cyclic group? If $R^*$ has two or more, is it compatible with it being cyclic?